# count row group by date consider days between start date and end date _ python

Tags: python

There are several data,

index |Start_date    | End_Date

1     |2020-01-01    | 2020-01-02

2     |2020-01-01    | 2020-01-03

3     |2020-01-02    | 2020-01-04

Thus I want to make the below using upon data

index |date          | count

1     |2020-01-01    | 2

2     |2020-01-02    | 3

3     |2020-01-03    | 2

4|2020-01-04    | 1

Comment: How can the count of `2020-01-02` is `3`?

Comment: So, I need count the during the date going,

1. 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 (= 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-02)
2. 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03(= 01-01 and 01-02 and 01-03)
3. 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-04(01-02 and 01-03-and 01-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you want count between two dates, you can use `datetime.date` module. For example:

```
count = (date(2020,1,2) - date(2020,1,1)).days # will return 1
```

Full code :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

data = [{
"Start_Date" : "2020-01-01",
"End_Date": "2020-01-02"
},{
"Start_Date" : "2020-01-01",
"End_Date": "2020-01-03"
},{
"Start_Date" : "2020-01-02",
"End_Date": "2020-01-04"
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

count = []
for i in range(len(df)):
  sd = [int(sd) for sd in df.at[i,'Start_Date'].split('-')]
  ed = [int(ed) for ed in df.at[i,'End_Date'].split('-')]
  count.append((date(ed[0],ed[1],ed[2]) - date(sd[0],sd[1],sd[2])).days)
df['count'] = count
df
```

The input :

| index | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-04 |

The output will be :

| index | Start_Date | End_Date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-04 | 2 |